# htaccess rewrites domain redirects

Tags: url, overrides, redirect, htaccess

I have been using this code to redirect visitors from a number of countries to
domain#2 (using GeoIP), which works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.two$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(TH|KH|BN|IN|LA|MY|MM|NP|PH|SG|ID|VN)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.two/$1 [L]
```

Now I would like to redirect all countries not listed above to be redirected
to domain.one.
How could I archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.one$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^(TH|KH|BN|IN|LA|MY|MM|NP|PH|SG|ID|VN)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.one/$1 [L]
```

The humble "!" is the key. It makes the condition work for all countries not in the list.